# Save serial number in Excel using WPF (OLEDB)

Tags: excel, wpf, oledb

My application in WPF allows user to save some data from text boxes into Excel file (using OLEDB connection). I wish to add feature that every time new row is saved into Excel file a sequence number is added into EventID column in that Excel file.

But I'm getting an error while running the application related to parameter @EventId saying: 'parameter has no default value'.
I expect I have written wrong sql1 command to generate the serial number.

I'd appreciate your help.

```
 private void btnSaveNewEvent1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        object eventName = txtEventName.Text;
        object typeValue = txtEventType.Text;
        object nameValue = txtAttributeName.Text;
        object attribvValue = txtAValue.Text;
        object descValue = txtEventDescrip.Text;


        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        String sql = null;
        String sql1 = null;
        MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='excel_file\\events2.xlsx'; " +
            "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\"");

        try
        {

            //SQL STATEMENT TO SAVE INSERTED BY THE USER VALUES FROM THE TEXT BOXES

            //SQL1 STATEMENT TO GENERATE EVENTID NUMBER EACH TIME THE USER SAVES NEW ROW OF DATA

            MyConnection.Open();
            myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
            sql = "Insert into [events$] (EventID,EventName, Type, Name, [Value], Description) values(@EventID,@EventName,@Type,@Name,@Val,@Desc)";
            myCommand.CommandText = sql;
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventID",sql1);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventName", eventName ?? DBNull.Value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", typeValue ?? DBNull.Value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", nameValue ?? DBNull.Value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val", attribvValue ?? DBNull.Value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Desc", descValue ?? DBNull.Value);
            myCommand1.Connection = MyConnection;
            sql1= "DECLARE @i int = 0 while @i < EventID BEGIN SET @i = EventID + 1 END";
            myCommand1.CommandText = sql1;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MyConnection.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            MyConnection.Close();

            Events eventsWindow = new Events();
            eventsWindow.dgData.Items.Refresh();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your command is running before command1 sql1 = null, That is what your problem is.
You need to set the value of sql1 before executing the command. If you really want the value to be null you need to use DBNull.Value as you have for the other parameters.

Comment: Thank You.I changed the sequence and the command1. Now it works well.